# Fetching internal API routes not being called in NextJS. Some work, some don't

Tags: next.js

My NextJs app uses fetch to call internal api routes, which connect to a Firebase Realtime Database. I have 7 api routes, of which 5 are called and 2 aren't (team and lobby) upon deployment. All the api routes work as expected when run locally. This is what the api folder looks like, each subfolder has a route.ts file.

[api folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSE5U.png)

For now I've focused on the api/lobby fetch call. The page where I run fetch is below:

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Lobby({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
  const division = params.id.split("_")[0];
  const [lobby, setLobby] = useState(emptyData.lobby);
  const [t, setT] = useState("Hello"); // I added this to test whether useEffect was being called

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      setT("Hello Github"); // This works, I render t and it shows Hello Github
      const response = await fetch("/api/lobby", {
        method: "GET",
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      setLobby(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <some html/>
```

The api/lobby route, simplified for this post:

```
import { emptyData } from "@/app/constants";
import { FirebaseLobby } from "@/app/types";
import { database } from "@/firebaseConfig";
import { ref, get } from "firebase/database";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  try {
    console.log("I'm in lobby"); // I expect to see this in the Vercel logs
    return NextResponse.json(lobbyData.val() as FirebaseLobby);
    return NextResponse.json(emptyData.lobby);
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
}
```

When run locally I get the "I'm in lobby" message, but on Vercel it never makes the fetch call to api/lobby.

The api/division and division page combo works. So I tried calling api/division from the lobby page, it worked. Then I tried calling api/lobby from the division page, didn't work, no api call is shown in Vercel (see below). However, if I look for the Function in Vercel I do find /api/lobby.

[vercel function calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r04h4.png)

The code for the division and lobby pages is basically identical, as is the code for the routes.

I've read the NextJS docs and gone through every stackoverflow post I could find, but at this point I probably missed something cause I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Don't call internal APIs. Refactor the logic into an utility function and call the function instead. Wrap the same function in your API, if you want to expose the API for other calls (not internal).